# How do I write a huge bytearray to file progressively and avoid that dreaded memory error

Tags: actionscript-3, air, arrays, file-writing

I'm working on an Air project that downloads huge (zip) files, then unzips them and finally deletes the original .zip file it downloaded.

Everything's running smoothly except when I want to write the unzipped file to disk.

Trouble is, I keep running into the issue of this little monster of an error.

```
Error: Error #1000: The system is out of memory.
```

Here's the part of the code that is giving me grief. This works perfectly when the file is small (tested on a 3 MB file) but as soon as I try one of my large files (458 MB), I get the error.

```
private function unzipFile()
    {
        var pulledFile:FZipFile;
        var index:int = 0;
        var chunkSize:int = 1000000;

        Console.log("Unzipping file...");
        var zip:FZip = new FZip();
        zip.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onUnzipComplete);
        var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();

        zip.load(new URLRequest(urlToUnzip));

        function onUnzipComplete(e:Event)
        {
            pulledFile = zip.getFileAt(0);
            var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(pulledFile.filename);
            fileStream.openAsync(file, FileMode.WRITE);
            writeChunk();
        }

        function writeChunk()
        {
            var bytesToGet:int = pulledFile.content.bytesAvailable;
            if (bytesToGet > chunkSize)
                bytesToGet = chunkSize;

            Console.log("Writing chunk " + (int((pulledFile.content.length - pulledFile.content.bytesAvailable) / chunkSize) + 1) + " of " + (int(pulledFile.content.length / chunkSize) + 1));

            var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            pulledFile.content.readBytes(fileData, 0, bytesToGet);

            fileStream.writeBytes(fileData, 0, fileData.length);

            if (index < pulledFile.content.bytesAvailable)
            {
                writeChunk();
                index += bytesToGet;
            }
            else
            {
                fileStream.close();
                Console.log("Unzipping complete");
            }
        }
    }
```

The code crashes specifically on the line

```
var bytesToGet:int = pulledFile.content.bytesAvailable;
```

How do I still progressively write content to a file without knowing how many bytes are available to me? If I don't have access to the `bytesAvailable` property, how do I know I'm done writing?

I'm using [the FZip library](https://github.com/claus/fzip) for decompression.

Comment: Instead of storing the remaining bytearray size in a local variable, try checking `if(pulledFile.content.bytesAvailable > 0)` and then take a chunk or smaller piece from the array.

Comment: I can't access bytesAvailable at all. Just tried what you suggested, can't trace it, can't put it in a conditional statement, nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was tough, but I figured it out. The trick is to use the "serialize" method of the `FZip` and avoid touching the properties of the content `ByteArray`altogether.

Here's the final code that works.

```
private function unzipFile()
    {
        var pulledFile:FZipFile;

        Console.log("Decompressing file...");
        var zip:FZip = new FZip();
        zip.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onUnzipComplete);

        var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();

        zip.load(new URLRequest(urlToUnzip));

        function onUnzipComplete(e:Event)
        {
            pulledFile = zip.getFileAt(0);
            var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("Easywatch/" + pulledFile.filename);
            fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
            zip.serialize(fileStream, false);
            fileStream.close();

            Console.log("Decompression complete");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have a zip file of 160MB and the file inside it is 516MB. I tried the approach above, but it's writing only 313MB of data(file is corrupt), without any errors. Am I missing something ?